# Downloading mail attachments damaging files

Tags: c#

i'm using C# to download the attachments on a mail message but all the files I download is damaged (specially PDF files), the code I;m using only download one attachment at the time (because are being moved based on criteria)
 The code I'm using:

```
byte[] allBytes = new byte[item.ContentStream.Length];
int bytesRead = item.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)item.ContentStream.Length);
string destinationFile = @Destination;
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
writer.Write(allBytes);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Possibly your mail attachment is encoded, for example using Base64. You need to decode it first.

Answer (score 2):

[BinaryWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netframework-4.8) is only meant to write primitive data to a file. It's not meant for stream operations. You can copy data from one stream to another with [Stream.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.8) eg:

```
using(var targetStream=new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    item.ContentStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
}
```

Comment: HI, I changed the Binary Writer for the Content Stream and It still doesn't work

Comment: New code: byte[] allBytes = new byte[item.ContentStream.Length];
int bytesRead = item.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)item.ContentStream.Length);
string destinationFile = @Destination;
 using(var targetStream=new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    item.ContentStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
}

Comment: If the original file is corrupt though, the local file will be corrupt as well. `allBytes` isn't needed anywhere. If the email library you use (which one?) doesn't decode the attachment contents, you'll end up exporting the wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `BinaryWriter`.  You already have the binary content, just write that to disk.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(destinationFile, allBytes)
```

Comment: I tried this method but the file is still not able to be open, I'm suspecting is the byte[] allBytes = new byte[item.ContentStream.Length]; since it gave me the same erratic result that the binary writer and both of the mothods use the allBytes to write the file

Comment: @JohnnyViquez if the attachment is bad, the saved file will be bad too. Besides, you didn't explain what `bad` means. Using a BinaryWriter is *definitely* wrong